# Canvas and context2d npm

Tags: node.js, canvas, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to use canvas in my React project. I have installed canvas with `npm install canvas --save`

and when I try to launch my server I am getting that weird error that I can't figure out where it is coming from...

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'parseFont' of undefined
./node_modules/canvas/lib/context2d.js
node_modules/canvas/lib/context2d.js:49
  46 |  * @api private
  47 |  */
  48 | 
> 49 | var parseFont = exports.parseFont = function(str) {
  50 |   var parsedFont;
  51 | 
  52 |   // Try to parse the font string using parse-css-font.
View compiled
__webpack_require__
/home/lucas/Bureau/test/webpack/bootstrap faf0efc1b256fd6e0167:678
  675 | };
  676 | 
  677 | // Execute the module function
> 678 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  679 | 
  680 | // Flag the module as loaded
  681 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/home/lucas/Bureau/test/webpack/bootstrap faf0efc1b256fd6e0167:88
  85 |      console.warn("[HMR] unexpected require(" + request + ") from disposed module " + moduleId);
  86 |      hotCurrentParents = [];
  87 |  }
> 88 |  return __webpack_require__(request);
  89 | };
  90 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  91 |  return {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js:17
  14 | , Canvas = canvas.Canvas
  15 | , Image = canvas.Image
  16 | , cairoVersion = canvas.cairoVersion
> 17 | , Context2d = require('./context2d')
  18 | , PNGStream = require('./pngstream')
  19 | , PDFStream = require('./pdfstream')
  20 | , JPEGStream = require('./jpegstream')
View compiled
./node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8904:30
__webpack_require__
/home/lucas/Bureau/test/webpack/bootstrap faf0efc1b256fd6e0167:678
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I also when I installed canvas I had some warning:

```
> canvas@1.6.7 install /home/lucas/Bureau/test/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

make : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/lucas/Bureau/test/node_modules/canvas/build »
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
  COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/color.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/ImageData.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/FontFace.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas.node
  COPY Release/canvas.node
make : on quitte le répertoire « /home/lucas/Bureau/test/node_modules/canvas/build »
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ canvas@1.6.7
added 230 packages in 17.478s
```

I have followed the Git instructions and installed everything it says to install, but I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:
The reason why you can't use it in your React app is exactly because

> You won't be able to use this module in the browser since it's built in C++ together with other compiled libraries.

*LinusU commented on Jan 28, 2016* Refer: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/284

Digging a little deeper:
Inside *canvas/lib/context2d.js*, Context2d is will be *undefined* in the browser.

We see that from, `Context2d = canvas.CanvasRenderingContext2d`, and

since `canvas = require('./bindings')` and 
*canvas/lib/bindings.js* requires a .node file, 
particularly *canvas.node*,
from `module.exports = require('../build/Release/canvas.node');`

It's not going to load properly in the browser.

... Unless someone builds the shim

> There have been discussions of adding a browser field to the package.json with a small shim though, I think that there is another package that wraps this with that currently...

*same Github thread as above*

Hope this saves some people some time with this issue!